# Either a b. Different Hoogle results after two years?

Tags: haskell, either, hoogle

I am following a video that was recorded about two years ago. The speaker enters `Either a b -> IO b` in the public Hoogle search input and the result contains (among others):

```
either :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Either a b -> c
```

If I [try it today](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Either%20a%20b%20-%3E%20IO%20b), this result is not found, which is a pity. Similar results are found, like

```
fromEither :: (Exception e, MonadIO m) => Either e a -> m a
```

but they are less ready-to-use.

**How can this be explained? Has the Hoogle search algorithm gotten stricter? Has Either changed?**

Comment: Not an answer but just a remark: https://github.com/ndmitchell/hoogle/blob/master/docs/TypeSearch.md defines how it works currently.

Comment: I would argue that your second result is actually a much better fit for the search than your first result. So I see this as an improvement!

Comment: I daresay that the version from today is definitely _much closer_ to what you searched for. The signature of `either` is very different from what you searched for; if Hoogle shows all just _remotely_ related signatures from hundreds of packages than how are you supposed to find the right one there?

Comment: Worse, this gets no results at all: `(a -> IO c) -> (b -> IO c) -> Either a b -> IO c`.

Comment: @dfeuer that, indeed, is a bit sad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code has changed completely since the last time you tried it. In particular, it now scales up to all of Stackage (~2K packages), gets updated every night and takes a bounded amount of time per query (certain queries like searching for the type `a` could make the old Hoogle take up a huge amount of time and memory). Completely rewriting the type search algorithm impacted almost all queries - some got better, some worse, and in some cases, what is better or worse is hard to define. [This blog post](https://neilmitchell.blogspot.com/2015/01/hoogle-5-is-coming.html) serves as an overview of what happened and [this issue tracker](https://github.com/ndmitchell/hoogle/issues) can be used for searches you think could be improved.